# Spring Webflux: Assertion for redirectUriTemplate to be not null, even though I am using OAuth 2.0 client credentials

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, clientcredential

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.4 with `spring-boot-starter-webflux`, `spring-boot-starter-security` and `spring-security-oauth2-client`.

With the reactive [`WebClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) I want to call [Auth0's management API](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2) using [OAuth 2.0 client credentials](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/client-credentials/) to get some user information.

I have followed [Baeldung's Spring WebClient and OAuth2 Support tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-oauth2). My `application.properties` looks like this:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.client-id=XXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.client-secret=YYY
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.auth0.token-uri=https://ZZZ.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token
```

My Spring `@Configuration` like this:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Auth0Configuration {

    @Value("${auth0.api.base-url}")
    private final String auth0ApiBaseUrl;

    @Bean
    WebClient auth0WebClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository reactiveClientRegistrationRepository) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                        reactiveClientRegistrationRepository,
                        new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("auth0");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .baseUrl(auth0ApiBaseUrl)
                .build();
    }

}
```

But when I make the first call with the `WebClient`, this error occurs:

```
2020-02-12 20:18:11.098 ERROR 1945 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [f0218135]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/oauth2/authorization/auth0"

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/oauth2/authorization/auth0" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(UriComponentsBuilder.java:212)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.expandRedirectUri(DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.authorizationRequest(DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.java:131)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.lambda$resolve$3(DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.java:121)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2199)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2007)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1881)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:112)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2199)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:184)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:81)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4105)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4105)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:174)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:174)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:293)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:78)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1638)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:112)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2199)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:346)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:184)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:81)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:255)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1637)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1637)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:121)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.fastPath(FluxIterable.java:333)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:198)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollectList.java:72)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromFluxOperator.subscribe(MonoFromFluxOperator.java:72)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.drain(FluxFilterWhen.java:295)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterWhen.java:134)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:243)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:201)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterWhen.java:194)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4105)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServerHandle.java:64)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServerBind$ChildObserver.onStateChange(TcpServerBind.java:228)
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:465)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:90)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:167)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

When following the stack trace I see that the property `redirectUriTemplate` in the [`ClientRegistration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/registration/ClientRegistration.html) is `null`. But since I am using client credentials a redirect URI shouldn't be needed at all.

Is there an error in my configuration? How can I make `WebClient` work with the client credentials flow?

Comment: `@Value("${auth0.api.base-url}")` what does this look like in your `application.properties`

Comment: @ThomasAndolf This is the value for the base URL of my requests. It resolves to https://my-tenant.eu.auth0.com.

Comment: `spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.auth0.token-uri` i cant find anything anywhere that this parameter exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application is working now with this configuration:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
class Auth0Configuration {

    // some properties

    @Bean
    WebClient auth0WebClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        var exchangeFilterFunction = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        exchangeFilterFunction.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(AUTH_0_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_ID);
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(auth0ApiBaseUrl)
                .filter(exchangeFilterFunction)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository reactiveClientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(
                ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(AUTH_0_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_ID)
                        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                        .tokenUri(auth0TokenUri)
                        .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.POST)
                        .clientId(auth0ClientId)
                        .clientSecret(auth0ClientSecret)
                        .scope()
                        .build()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials(clientCredentialsGrantBuilder -> {
                            WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient = new WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
                            accessTokenResponseClient.setWebClient(WebClient.builder()
                                    .filter((request, next) -> {
                                        FormInserter<String> body = (FormInserter<String>) request.body();
                                        body.with("audience", auth0Audience);
                                        return next.exchange(request);
                                    })
                                    .build());
                            clientCredentialsGrantBuilder.accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient);
                        }
                )
                .build()
        );
        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

}
```

Comment: I realized that I had to remove library ''org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security" from gradle file and things worked fine.  All we needed is 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client' and fist two methods from Harold L. Brown's solution.